# How can I add Commerce Wishlist share mail template variables from form?

Tags: theming, commerce, emails, 9

I am trying to add 2 additional form fields to the Wishlist Share form where the user input will be rendered in the email. I have been able to add the fields to the form, but I am not sure how to add the user's input in the email twig template.

Here is how I have updated the form() function:

```
  public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    // Workaround for core bug #2897377.
    $form['#id'] = Html::getId($form_state->getBuildInfo()['form_id']);

    $form['to'] = [
      '#type' => 'email',
      '#title' => $this->t('Recipient Email'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

// COMBAK my edit

    $form['sender_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Your Name'),
      '#required' => FALSE,
    ];

    $form['sender_message'] = [
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => $this->t('Your Message'),
      '#required' => FALSE,
    ];

// COMBAK eo my edit

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function actions(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $actions['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Send email'),
      '#submit' => ['::submitForm'],
    ];
    if ($this->isAjax()) {
      $actions['submit']['#ajax']['callback'] = '::ajaxSubmit';
    }

    return $actions;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_wishlist\Entity\WishlistInterface $wishlist */
    $wishlist = $this->entity;
    $to = $form_state->getValue('to');

    // COMBAK: my added vars
    $sender_name = $form_state->getValue('sender_name');
    $sender_message = $form_state->getValue('sender_message');

    $this->wishlistShareMail->send($wishlist, $to, $sender_name, $sender_message);

    $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('Shared the wishlist to @recipient.', [
      '@recipient' => $to,
    ]));
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($wishlist->toUrl('user-form'));
  }
```

This is the function that calls the mailHandler that I have updated:

```
public function send(WishlistInterface $wishlist, $to, $sender_name, $sender_message) {
    $owner = $wishlist->getOwner();

    $subject = $this->t('Check out my @site-name wishlist', [
      '@site-name' => $this->configFactory->get('system.site')->get('name'),
    ]);
    $body = [
      '#theme' => 'commerce_wishlist_share_mail',
      '#wishlist_entity' => $wishlist,
      // COMBAK: my added vars
      '#sender_name' => $sender_name,
      '#sender_message' => $sender_message,
    ];
    $params = [
      'id' => 'wishlist_share',
      'from' => $owner->getEmail(),
      'wishlist' => $wishlist,
    ];

    return $this->mailHandler->sendMail($to, $subject, $body, $params);
  }
```

And this is the preprocees function provided by the commerce wishlist module:

```
function template_preprocess_commerce_wishlist_share_mail(array &$variables) {
  /** @var Drupal\commerce_wishlist\Entity\WishlistInterface $wishlist */
  $wishlist = $variables['wishlist_entity'];
  $wishlist_url = $wishlist->toUrl('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE]);

  $variables['wishlist_url'] = $wishlist_url->toString();

  // COMBAK: my added vars
  //$sender_name = $variables['sender_name'];
}
```

And finally the twig template for the email itself:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Template for the wishlist share email.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - wishlist_entity: The wishlist entity.
 * - wishlist_url: The wishlist url.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
<p>
  {% trans %}Check out my wishlist!{% endtrans %}
</p>

<p>
  {% trans %}I use my wishlist for keeping track of items I am interested in.{% endtrans %} <br>
  {% trans %}To see the list in the store and buy items from it, <a href="{{ wishlist_url }}">click here</a>.{% endtrans %}
</p>

<p>
  {% trans %}Thanks for having a look!{% endtrans %}
</p>
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to access the variables I added to the body[] array in the twig template.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the right way to do it, but I included the form data in the $_SESSION variable as I could not find a more appropriate way.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_wishlist\Entity\WishlistInterface $wishlist */
    $wishlist = $this->entity;
    $to = $form_state->getValue('to');

    // COMBAK: MY CODE
    $_SESSION['sender_data'] = [];

    $sender_data = [
        '#theme' => 'commerce_wishlist_share_mail',
        '#sender_name' => $form_state->getValue('sender_name'),
        '#sender_message' => $form_state->getValue('sender_message')
    ];

    $_SESSION['sender_data'] = $sender_data;
    // COMBAK: EO MY CODE

    $this->wishlistShareMail->send($wishlist, $to);

    $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('Shared the wishlist to @sender_name at the following email address: @recipient.', [
      '@recipient' => $to,
      '@sender_name' => $sender_data['#sender_name']
    ]));
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($wishlist->toUrl('user-form'));
  }
```

```
function template_preprocess_commerce_wishlist_share_mail(array &$variables) {
  /** @var Drupal\commerce_wishlist\Entity\WishlistInterface $wishlist */
  $wishlist = $variables['wishlist_entity'];
  $wishlist_url = $wishlist->toUrl('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE]);

  $variables['wishlist_url'] = $wishlist_url->toString();

  // COMBAK: MY CODE
  $sender_data = $_SESSION['sender_data'];
  $variables['sender_name'] = $sender_data['#sender_name'];
  $variables['sender_message'] = $sender_data['#sender_message'];
  $_SESSION['sender_data'] = [];
  // COMBAK: EO MY CODE
}
```